# Why am i getting a ENOTEMPTY error?

Tags: windows, meteor

So i create a default meteor app.
Its runs great.
Now I add a simple insert in the startup function.
its is now giving me exceptions.

Here is my app.js code:

```
Book = new Meteor.Collection("book");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to app_01.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Book.find().count() === 0) {
      var names = ["Ada Lovelace",
                   "Grace Hopper",
                   "Marie Curie",
                   "Carl Friedrich Gauss",
                   "Nikola Tesla",
                   "Claude Shannon"];
      for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        Book.insert({name: names[i], score: Math.floor(Math.random()*10)*5});
    }
  });
}
```

And here is the exception I am getting:

```
No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty 'C:\Users\Office\Workspace\Code\Meteor\app_01\.meteor\local\build\server'
    at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:456:18)
    at Object.module.exports.rm_recursive (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\lib\files.js:256:10)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\lib\files.js:254:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object.module.exports.rm_recursive (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\lib\files.js:252:9)
    at _.extend.write_to_directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\lib\bundler.js:493:11)
    at Object.exports.bundle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\lib\bundler.js:685:12)
    at exports.run.restart_server (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\meteor\run.js:615:26)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\meteor\run.js:726:9

Please fix the problem and restart.
```

The console gives me no useful information at all.

Some more info:
I am using the windows version of meteor 0.5.4
My code has both tabs and spaces as indentation (should that be a problem?)

---

to add to my perplexity:
If i run the leaderboard example, it runs perfectly.

When I run the default project with my modified startup code, i get the exception. >.<

---

More info:
when the server crashed, the mongod service was still running in windows. In my infinite wisdom, i thought I'll kill it and maybe try a fresh restart of it.

now i get a new error:

```
PS C:\Users\Office\Workspace\Code\Meteor\app_01> meteor
[[[[[ C:\Users\Office\Workspace\Code\Meteor\app_01 ]]]]]

Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Can't start mongod

MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
Check to make sure that MongoDB is able to write to its database directory.
```

---

Edit: now deleted the .meteor/local/db contents. we are now back to the ENOTEMPTY error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the directory is not getting deleted during the bundling operation.

So when this happens, Stop your server with `ctrl + c`.

Then delete the contents of `.meteor\local\db` directory as well as `.meteor\local\builds` directory and run the server again using `meteor` command.

Not an ideal way, but it works.

Comment: did. Now am back to the first error:
Running on: http://localhost:3000/
No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this on my mac and on my Windows machine, it works fine for me. (Copied and pasted your code into app.js, did not change anything anywhere else, as I understood this is what you did).

There are two ways to go on:

1. You try `meteor reset`. **Warning:** This will empty any databases you had within this app, but I think there isn't anything all to important in there at the moment?
2. You delete the app and make a new one using `meteor create appname`, and copy the source code from above into app.js.

I think investing too much time and effort is not worth it, since it is not an app close to production stage. If, however, creating a new app causes the same problem, it will get interesting =)

**EDIT:** Just searched around and found this: https://github.com/TomWij/meteor/issues/18
Scroll down to the answer; apparently it might be your antivirus scanner preventing Meteor from rebuilding it. Is that possible?
Also, are you starting Meteor from anything else than cmd.exe? I just read through the issue on GitHub, and things seem to be pretty gnarly when using anything else than cmd.exe (eg the GitHub Bash Shell)

Comment: there's nothing custom in that directory. it was a default meteor project created using `meteor create app`. i only added the leaderboard insert statement in the startup code.

Comment: I was reading the exactly same issue. I just added my comments there:

Answer (score 1):

Once my pull request goes in, this issue should be resolved:

https://github.com/TomWij/meteor/pull/56